Generic method for storing polymorphic relationships in Laravel
I’ve implemented two models, Post and Video, along with a polymorphic relationship for Comment. I understand that I can save comments using the following approach:
public function store(Post $post) {
    $post->comments()->save(...);
}

public function store(Video $video) {
    $video->comments()->save(...);
}

However, I’m wondering how to simplify this with a more generic method in a CommentController, something like this:
public function store(Model $model) {
    $model->comments()->create([]);
}

How to implement this?

I think for implicit binding, the variable's name needs to match whatever is inside of {} in the Route definition, and $model doesn't match post or video, so it's treating it as a String. You'd probably have to do posts/{model}/comments and videos/{model}/comments, then store(Model $model) (since both Post and Video should extend Model).

How I've solved it for now:
I've created a Commentable trait:
trait Commentable
{
    public function comments(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }


    public function storeComment(StoreCommentRequest $request)
    {
        $comment = new Comment([
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
            'content' => $request->get('content'),
        ]);

        $this->comments()->save($comment);

        return new CommentResource($comment);
    }
}

Then I added this trait to Post and Video models and added a storeComment function to both PostController and VideoController, like this:
function storeComment(Post $post, StoreCommentRequest $request)
{
    return $post->storeComment($request);
}

And this is my updated route:
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('posts/{post}/comments', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'storeComment']);
});

